# Проблема с тестированием Travis CI

Tags: java, travis

При тестирование, после минуты возникает ошибка

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project my-program: Could not resolve dependencies for project com:my-program:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find JUnit:junit:jar:4.4 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Проблема, в JUnit? Но у меня в проекте лежит библиотека.

Comment: в .m2 есть JUnit:junit:jar:4.4 там где Travis CI собирает?